# How can I delete items from CQ Workflow Inbox?

Tags: aem

How can I access the list of emails which are sent by a workflow ??

What I want here is If there are more than 100 emails in my workflow email console at this location : libs/cq/workflow/content/inbox.html

I need to delete if they are of no use, or lets say if some of them are of because of failure of any step. Where exactly these are being stored in CRX ?? when I check /libs/cq/workflow/content/inbox node, I do not see a list of these emails.

So in short my requirement will be like " I want to delete the already existing emails from CQ Workflow inbox when my payload is same".

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be helpful for others so I am putting it here.

In my workflow process java code, I picked up the workflow state by using WorkFlowStates and after getting the state("RUNNING") I compared its Item with all the Items inside instanses and if they match I terminated the workflow.

This way it worked.

This can also be helpful in the Workflow STALE related issues.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

In the CRX, you will find the workflow instances (which is what you are viewing through inbox.html) in `/etc/workflow/instances/[date YYYY-MM-DD]/`.

However, it's probably tidier for you to manage running workflow instances through the console at `http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/workflow/content/console.html`.

Answer (score 3):

Adobe CQ 5.6.1 Provides a built in Workflow Purge Scheduler in Felix Console Configuration /system/console/configMgr, following configuration can be made to this Scheduler:

Job Name

Workflow Status: COMPLETED/RUNNING

Models To Purge: Leave it blank for all models else specify ones only wanted to be purged.

Cron expression: Time when the scheduler should be triggered

Workflow Age: Workflows old by number of days. 7 specific as per ticket description.

Also we have a JMX Console to purge the same explicitly without waiting for scheduler to purge them:
/system/console/jmx/com.adobe.granite.workflow%3Atype%3DMaintenance

Here are some of the blogs which shows how to achieve the same http://labs.sixdimensions.com/blog/dan-klco/2013-10-03/new-aem-561-workflow-purge-scheduler.
http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/workflow-monitor-via-jmx.html
and http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/howtopurgewf.html.

Hope this will be helpful to those who are using CQ 5.6.1.